# OpenWeatherMap API giving inaccurate results

Tags: openweathermap

I am trying to query the api like this:

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=kuwait&APPID=[key]&units=metric&type=like

However, it's giving me back the result related to a country "PE".. I downloaded the country code json file referenced on the site, and searched through all cities with the word: Kuwait, and there's only 1 city which is: "Kuwait City" and one country which is "Kuwait". Why is the API getting back the country "PE" when searching for "kuwait"?

I also used the &type=like, so I would probably get the right data, but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When you search try search for "State of Kuwait" it's working for me.

for the link change "q=" to "id=285570"

"id": 285570,

"name": "State of Kuwait",

"country": "KW",

"coord": {

"lon": 47.75,

"lat": 29.5

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=285570&APPID=[Key]&units=metric&type=like

http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=285570&APPID=[Key]&units=metric&type=like